# Organizing the files of a project for multiplatform and easy-to-use

Tags: c++, github, organization, code-organization

Several years ago I created a C++ project. I used to write the code using nano and I compiled and linked it using a Makefile.

I simply had all the files into a single directory (including .cpp, .h and the Makefile itself).

For instance, I had a single inc.h file which was included in every single .cpp file, for example, something I now acknowledge as not very clean.

I would like to upload it to Github to make it accessible for anyone that wants to use it, with the problem being I can't seem to find any *guide* on how should I arrange the files (As there is, e.g., for [creating packages in R](https://methodsblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/building-your-first-r-package/)). I have tried using Code::Blocks but I haven't managed to make the project work, so,

Can anyone point me to a guide that explains how to properly organize the code and data for C++ projects?

Comment: If the project works with all the sources in the same directory, go with that. If it gains any traction (most projects don't), others can always re-arrange things.

Answer (score 1):

C++ itself doesn't have any style guide as to how to organize project files. It's one of the many little things that make package managers so difficult to realize. Every developer chooses their own organization, so if it works for you, just keep it in one folder. If you want to experiment with, e.g., separate header and cpp folders, there are examples around the internet, to be found when searching something similar to "makefile headers and source in separate directory".

For makefiles, you'd probably have to include something like

```
# preprocessor flags
CPPFLAGS :=  -I[path-to-headers]
```

in the <del>line calling the compiler</del>  makefile

Answer (score 1):

Most of the rules for C++ projects are project-specific, probably it's the main reason why there's no definitive guide. A couple of most generic recommendations I can think of (can be not relevant in your case):

- Will your users need to include your header files? In this case put such headers into a separate "include" folder. Rationale: to avoid mistakes of including wrong header (one that is not part of your API), and to simplify analysis of your public API. I don't understand the rule to put all headers separately from .cpp files (e.g. default filter of VisualStudio projects), some headers can be for internal usage only.
- Build to different folders (e.g. "bin" for shared libraries and executables or "lib" for static libraries) for each supported architecture and configuration. e.g.:

  bin
  |-- debug
  |--|-- x32
  |--|-- x64
  |-- release
  |--|-- x32
  |--|-- x64
  ...
  Rationale: simplify distribution and usage from external code.
- you asked "how to properly organize the code and **data**". If you allow to provide some external configuration, or just general data, make sure you allow to specify its location instead of just hardcoding it. It's fine to hardcode the default location though. Ideally your API allows to specify the location in runtime if this makes sense in your case, or compile time option e.g. as an argument to your build script. Rationale: it will be much easier to test on different datasets/configs.